# How do I create culture appropriate date strings that match a specific layout?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, datetime-format

This is C# (so .Net). I want to create a date string that is displayed in the correct order for the culture the code is running under that matches each of the following (en_US formatting):

- ToString("MMMM d, yyyy")
- ToString("ddd, MMM dd")

There's no single letter equivalent like "d" or "f" to give me the correct cultural output. Is there a way to convert from en_US to another culture?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.ToStirng` has two overloads that accept `IFormatProvider` arguments with one also accepting a format specifier.  `CultureInfo` implements the `IFormatProvider` interface.  Example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString( "d", new CultureInfo("fr-fr") )
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but that works for "d" but not for "MMMM d, yyyy". WHat I'm asking may be logically impossible because what is the French standard where we do "November 3, 2023" - probably not a conversion that can be comprehensively handled in code.